# Call Objective-C from Go with UTF-8 string

Tags: objective-c, macos, go, utf-8

I'm trying to call an Objective-C function from Go; this works just fine but my problem shows up with UTF-8 strings. I can't figure it out how to create an `NSString*` in the Go code, or how to pass a UTF-8 string via `char*`.

```
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -x objective-c
#cgo LDFLAGS: -framework Cocoa
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

void printUTF8(const char * iconPath) {
    NSLog(@"%s", iconPath);
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    goString := "test 漢字 test\n"
    fmt.Print(goString)
    cString := C.CString(goString)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cString))

    C.printUTF8(cString)
}
```

And as expected the output is:

> test 漢字 test

> test Êº¢Â≠ó test

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your objective-C code, you want:

```
void printUTF8(const char * iconPath) {
    // NSLog(@"%s", iconPath);
    NSLog(@"%@", @(iconPath)); // "test 漢字 test"
}
```

Using the boxed expression `@(iconPath)` ensures a valid NSString is created. For example if a bad `UTF-8` sequence is passed (e.g. try ["Fr\xe9d\xe9ric"](https://play.golang.org/p/DvvjG-3cRkw)) it will safely render to `null`.